# Configuring development, staging and production versions of a WordPress site

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have an already-in-production Wordpress-powered site.  I would like to create both a MAMP-powered development copy of this site on my local machine as well as a staging copy that lives on my web host.  When the time comes, I would push the content from local dev to staging, and staging to production after testing.

In terms of properly adding all the content to all three sites, I did see [this article](http://codex.wordpress.org/Running_a_Development_Copy_of_WordPress) in the Codex but I think I can get away with simpler method if I:

1. Download the production site content as an XML file using "Tools > Export" under the WP Dashboard.
2. Import the XML file into phpMyAdmin on my local MAMP site.
3. Make sure all the plugin configs match.
4. Create another XML file using "Tools > Export" on the MAMP side, then import it into the new staging site.
5. Change the DB name, UN, and PW info in the staging site's wp-config file.
6. To move the XML file from staging to production, I would repeat steps 4. The wp-config file is already up and running so there's no need to change anything here.

Also, since I changed the database's 'wp_' table prefix on production, I'm assuming that I need to do the same for both the development and staging environments.

I'm not good with MySQL and have only used phpMyAdmin a little which is the reason I'm asking this question. Did I miss something major and am I about to spectacularly crash-and-burn my site if I do all of this?

Answer (score 0):

I think just make sure the database specified in wp-config.php matches the version.

ie.

```
development wp-config.php specifies wp_devdb
staging wp-config.php specifies wp_stagedb
production wp-config.php specified wp_productiondb
```

creating the databases (using mamp locally)

```
mysql -u root -p
```

(then enter your password)

```
mysql->create database wp_devdb
->create database wp_devdb
```

Do not drop any table if it is important, ie your production table should not be dropped unless you want a fresh install

Comment: user1439659: Thanks for responding! I've already created the development db manually and MAMP and will do the same when I set up the staging sub-domain. Just so I get it: all have to do is add those names to each environment's corresponding wp-config file and I'm good, correct?